# I want to search and replace multiple values in a table column in one MYsql query

Tags: mysql, replace

Query to Where X update Y and where A update B in a Mysql Table column.

How can I Do this in MYsql in one query on the same column in a specific table.
I want to search and replace multiple values in a table column.

Conditions in table1 in column1

```
Where X update Y 
and
Where a update b
and
Where 1 update 2
and
Where 3 update 4
and
Where value1 update value 2
```

And so on.

I can individually do this but how can I do this faster? Is there a mysql function to help me with this?

I have about 120 columns with 200 search and replace/update values for each column.

Thanks.

Comment: Or also let me know if this i not possible so i stop banging my head about getting this done in an innovative way.

Comment: Your question is very confusing. What do you mean by `Where 1 update 2`. What is `1` in this context? Where does it come from?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
update table table set A = if(conditionA, newA, A), B = if(conditionB, newB, B)
```

But I expect it will be slower than 2 separate updates, because it is trying to reset every row's value back to itself when it doesn't match the condition.

You could optimise it somewhat by adding:

```
update table table set A = if(conditionA, newA, A), B = if(conditionB, newB, B)
where conditionA or conditionB
```

This might be quicker than 2 queries in some circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
UPDATE table1
SET
    col1 = CASE WHEN col2 THEN a ELSE col1 END,
    col3 = CASE WHEN col4 THEN b ELSE col3 END
```

Note that this sets a value back to itself if the condition fails, effectively causing it to be unchanged.